# "Cannot find 'RealmProperty' in scope" when trying to use optional double, Swift

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I'm using Realm Sync to store data for my iOS app, coded in Swift. I wanted to create an optional double property (budget) for a Realm object (User_budgets). I created the object in the Realm schema and then copied in the Data model SDK that Realm produces which is as below:

```
import Foundation
import RealmSwift

class User_budgets: EmbeddedObject {
    let budget = RealmProperty<Double>()
    @objc dynamic var date: Date? = nil
}
```

I then get the error: "Cannot find 'RealmProperty' in scope". I tried changing the code to the below:

```
@objc dynamic var budget: Double? = nil
```

But then I get the error: "Property cannot be marked @objc because its type cannot be represented in Objective-C"

I've had a search but can't seem to find anyone who's had this issue before. There's an easy work around, which is simply to make the budget property required (non-optional), but it would be good to know how to be able to create optional double properties in the future. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Just a FYI - you don't need to create objects in Realm Schema in the console first. If you create an Object in your App, Realm will automatically create that object in the server as well.

Comment: That's really interesting. I have to say it doesn't quite match up with my experience using Realm Sync up to now, but presumably this just means I'm doing something wrong? For example, I just updated one of the properties of one of my Realm objects in Xcode to be non-optional, and when I then tested the app it crashed, and the solution was to go to the Realm App in the MongoDB GUI and update the schema by adding that property to the list of properties that are "required". I then had to reinitialise the sync. Does this match up with what you'd expect?

Comment: Creating a fresh object, as in my comment above, is an additive change. *Additive changes* don't require any other action; Realm will just create the object, or add the additional property to an existing object. However, *updating* an existing property  (e.g. changing from optional to non-optional) or removing a property is a *destructive change* and requires additional steps. So yes that matches the expected process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you're using the wrong definition for that optional as it's only available in beta 10.8.0-beta.0:

What you have is

```
let budget = RealmProperty<Double>()
```

and for all other releases it should be

```
let budget = RealmOptional<Double>()
```

See [RealmProperty and RealmOptional](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/sdk/ios/fundamentals/object-models-and-schemas/#property-attributes)

oh and here's a link to all of the [Support Property Types](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/sdk/ios/data-types/supported-property-types/#std-label-ios-supported-property-types)

Comment: Thanks Jay really appreciate that!